# LOB applications and AGPL

Tags: agpl-3.0

I understand that SaaS applications are considered to be "distributed" or "conveyed" when they are used, what about LOB applications? For example an eCommerce site which has a sales application, a support forum application and an internal inventory application?  Where the three may share some common code, but are hosted separately (possibly on different servers)

Would using an AGPL library/binary in the forum software result in requiring either the inventory application or the sales application to be AGPL?

Comment: "*I understand that SaaS applications are considered to be "distributed" or "conveyed" when they are used*" is not correct.  As AGPLv3 s0 says, "*To "convey" a work means any kind of propagation that enables other parties to make or receive copies. Mere interaction with a user through a computer network, with no transfer of a copy, is not conveying*".  It's difficult to answer a question that starts with a flatly-incorrect statement; would you like to amend the question?  It would also help if you could briefly explain *LOB*, since I for one am not familiar with the term.

Comment: @MadHatter: top hit on google says "An LOB application is one of the set of critical computer applications that are vital to running an enterprise. LOB applications are usually large programs that contain a number of integrated capabilities and tie into databases and database management systems."

Comment: @jmoreno then I guess I'm also unclear about why copyright and licensing would apply differently to them than to any other software, and if it doesn't, why the LOBbiness of the software is relevant.

Comment: they may or may not interact with non-employee's, Interaction is for the purpose of working with the business and is not a product in and of itself, although that can get a bit ambivalent (investment firm that allow one to buy and sell stock, also shows how the stock performed, which might be considered SasS).